# I am able to switch to webview in real device but unable to swicth to webview on emulator.Appium version used is 1.7.2

Tags: android, android-webview, appium, selenium-chromedriver, appium-android

When I run the code on real device it works fine but when I run the same code on emulator it gives displays the webview context but gives the following error:
io.appium.java_client.NoSuchContextException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64)) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'Sanjays-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10ca:4ed3:43d2:24ed%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {Browser_Name: Chrome, appActivity: mobile.zineone.com.function..., appPackage: mobile.zineone.com.function, autoGrantPermissions: true, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {Browser_Name: Chrome, appActivity: mobile.zineone.com.function..., appPackage: mobile.zineone.com.function, autoGrantPermissions: true, deviceName: Moto G, platformName: android, unicodeKeyboard: true}, deviceManufacturer: unknown, deviceModel: Android SDK built for x86_64, deviceName: emulator-5556, deviceScreenSize: 1440x2560, deviceUDID: emulator-5556, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 6.0, takesScreenshot: true, unicodeKeyboard: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 6e181e7b-f5b1-4357-882a-38d7de73d099

Answer (score 0):

If you check the error you got more closely, you will see it states:

`Original error: session not created exception:
Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0
Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106`

Chromedriver is the intermediate handler that allows Appium communicate with actual Chrome browser on your device.

The thing is: **each version** of chromedriver supports only **specific range** of chrome versions, in your case **chromedriver 2.33 supports Chrome v60-62**

Your real device is having chrome browser version of 60-62 and it works there.

But your emulator most likely has old version of browser.

Your actions:

1. Check browser version on emulator
2. Find matching chrome driver [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and download it to machine, where you host appium server.
3. Use `chromedriverExecutable` capability to provide absolute path to your new chromedriver when you create Appium session
4. Enjoy :)